# Why are my Angular Material Components displaying wrong?

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

I wanted to install Angular Material in my new Project following the tutorial from Angular Material (https://v5.material.angular.io/guide/getting-started).

When im adding a Angular Material component it is not showing correctly. This is my code:

```
<a routerLink='/'>Back</a>

<form [formGroup]="registerForm">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="firstName">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label i18n>Last Name</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="lastName">
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

and this is how it looks:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXQoS.png)

The label is missing completly and the style is totally different.

Comment: the link you provided points to Angular Material v5, the current one is v15. Are you sure you install correctly the right version on your personal project?

Comment: I tried using the correct version guide, but the error still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Before angular v8, there is no external library integration support. In the angular v8 and above versions you can use `ng add` command then the target projects will installed your project with all its default configuration.

Since you are dealing with angular v5 (I assume v5 because you are installing angular material v5) you need to add theme css manually on your styles.scss

```scss
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

If you are using angular v8 or above please find matched version of the angular material and add the project using above command.

```bash
# remove xx.xx.xx if you are using latest version
ng add @angular/material@xx.xx.xx
```

Comment: Oh yes, you are right, i didn't mention that i'm pointing at v5. 

I am using Angular 14 so i tried to use ng add @angular/material@v14-lts. This has added me some styles for 'html' and 'body' and added style references to my angular.json (angular material theme in node_modules). Unfortunately the error still exists.

Comment: Well i got the Problem. I did not import the MatInputModule.